# A problem with saving 'Time' variable in database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to save "02:22:22" for example in my MySQL database. Everything is working correctly as far as I can see in my code, but when the value is saved in MySQL, it changes to one hour up. So always: "03:22:22". When I retrieve the value it is back to normal: "02:22:22". How can I fix this and why is it happening?

Comment: What is the type of the column in MySQL? Might be easier to solve if we had code.

Comment: I am not sure, hibernate is doing the tables for me. My property looks like this :

Comment: @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hours:minutes:seconds")
    private Time duration;

Comment: check the timezone of the mysql server

Comment: thanks, that helped me

Answer (score 2):

fixed it by adding &serverTimezone=Europe/Sofia in the db url in the properties

Answer (score 2):

## `LocalTime` and JDBC 4.2

You may be seeing a time zone adjustment being injected into the data exchange. You can avoid such a problem by using JDBC with *java.time* types.

The other Answer and Comments suggesting you play around with default time zones are misguided in my opinion — better to be explicit in your Java code about time zones rather than rely implicitly on defaults.

JDBC 4.2 added required support for exchanging some of the *java.time* types. This includes the [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class for representing a time-of-day without a date and a without a time zone.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "02:22:22" ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , lt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalTime lt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalTime.class ) ;
```

Notice that **nowhere in this code did we use strings** when communicating with the database. If you use this code with a column in your database of type `TIME`, then you will have no issues with time zones.

I do not use Hibernate or JPA, so I cannot speak to that except to say that I know both JPA 2.2 and Hibernate added support for *java.time* types. Discussed [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-java-8-date-and-time-types/), [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-java-time), and [other places](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jpa+2.2+java.time&t=osx&ia=web).